# fixed an html anchor tag at a specific point

Tags: html, css

I have the below HTML. I want to fix the position of the "View All" anchor tag at a particular position. Instead the anchor tag moves as the value in the dropdown changes (i.e according to the length of the changed value in dropdown).

```
<div class="row " style="margin-left:75pt;">
            <div class="dropdown" style="width:300px;display:inline;">
                <label class="text-center" id ="categories"  style="margin-top:10pt;font-size:14pt;"> Deals on</label>&nbsp;
                <button data-toggle="dropdown" class=" btn dropdown-toggle dropdown-menu-hover-color text-center" style="padding:0px 0px;background-color:white;" href="#"><label style="font-size:14pt; color: #191970;" >{{currentCategory}}</label>&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu submenu-hover-color dropdown-menu-scroll"  style="margin:0;">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="{{page.category_id}}" ng-click="changeCategory(page.category_id);" ng-repeat="page in dropdownCategoryList" ng-model="category_id">{{page.category_name}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div style="display:inline;" ng-show="deals"><a href="#" class="view-all-category"> View All</a></div>
            <div style="display:inline;" ng-hide="deals">&nbsp;&nbsp;<label class="text-center" style="margin-top:10pt;font-size:12pt;color: #909090;;">No deals found, please select a different category. </label></div>    
        </div>
```

Any pointers on how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried making your `ul.dropdown-menu` have `position:absolute`?

Comment: @David ul.dropdown-menu has position:absolute. Hence it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

try using following html:

```
<div style="display:inline; position: fixed; top: 100px;" ng-show="deals"><a href="#" class="view-all-category"> View All</a></div>
```

Set the 'top' value as per your need. I think it should help you.

Comment: I don't want the anchor tag to move as the page scrolls.I just want the anchor tag at a particular position on the page irrespective of the other elements on the page.